# DB Frameworks for .NET Core database-first

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a client whose SQL database is decades old. Software engineers do not have access to update schema objects and DBAs do not use code-first to update the database.

.NET Core 6 is a requirement for me. Since `.edmx` is not a part of .NET Core, does anyone have recommendations for an ORM that implements a "database-first" approach?

Comment: Use EF Core- have a look at EF Core Power Tools

Comment: Thank you ErikEJ
scaffold-dbcontext "Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=[DatabaseName];Integrated Security=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -ContextDir [contextDirName] -OutputDir [ModelDirName] -Namespace [ModelNamespace] -Context PortalDbContext -Force -NoOnConfiguring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [ErikEJ](https:////https://stackoverflow.com/users/183934/erikej).

EntityFramework tools allows me to keep the db models updated without having to deal with migrations.

> scaffold-dbcontext "Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=[DatabaseName];Integrated Security=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -ContextDir [ContextDir] -OutputDir [ModelDir] -Namespace [ModelDir] -Context PortalDbContext -Force -NoOnConfiguring

More info on scaffold-dbcontext

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell

Answer (score 0):

You can [reverse engineer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) an existing database schema, which is a "database-first" workflow.